# framework7 возврат на страницу физической кнопкой

Tags: framework7

В framework7 для перехода на новую страницу использую:

```
<a href="{{name_page}}.html" class="item-link item-content">
```

Всё прекрасно работает, новые страницы открываются.
Но если на телефоне нажать кнопку "назад" (физическую кнопку, не на странице), то он не возвращаться на предыдущую страницу и выходит с сайта.

Я так понимаю что проблема в том что url всегда один, не важна какая страница.

Как сделать что бы при нажатии кнопки "назад" на устройстве и в браузере (около url есть вперёд, назад и перезагрузка) открывалась предыдущая страница?

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо переходы делать не напрямую, а через роутеры. Секция в начальном app,
на каждый html свой роутер

```
  routes: [
{name: 'main', path: '/main/', url: './pages/main.html'}
{ name: 'app', path: '/', url: './index.html' }  ]
```

Тогда сам переход в html

```
<a href="/main/" >Далее ></a>
```

Вот тогда включается history, которая будет запоминать переходы. А так вы заменяете текущий html. И еще один момент, в каждом html надо прописать через data-name название роутера

```
 <div class="page" data-name="main">
    class="view view-main">
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var myApp = new Framework7({
   pushState: true,
});
```

Comment: Пишите более развернутые ответы, с пояснением того что именно делает ваш код.